# image overlaping with main div border

Tags: html, css, image, containers, border

image in a div should fit div and i can manage that. But where i struggle is to make image to be over the border AND still to be contained within the main div.

```css
.box {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    max-width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  
}


.image {
position: absolute;  
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="box__image" src="#" alt="#">
  <div>
  
  <div class="random">
    <p class="box__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ipsum quis lacus sagittis vehicula eget sed diam. Nam quis sapien sem. Phasellus vehicula blandit nunc vel cursus. Nullam felis nisl, molestie ut ipsum sit amet, vulputate tempus nibh. </p>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I see that you have specified `position: absolute;` but you haven to actually specified its positioning with `top` or `left`. You need to do this to achieve your desired positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `position: absolute;` you also need to specify your positioning with `top`/`bottom` and/or `left`/`right`.

```css
.box {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
  
}
.image {
    position: absolute;  
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="box__image" src="#" alt="#">
  <div>
  
  <div class="random">
    <p class="box__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu ipsum quis lacus sagittis vehicula eget sed diam. Nam quis sapien sem. Phasellus vehicula blandit nunc vel cursus. Nullam felis nisl, molestie ut ipsum sit amet, vulputate tempus nibh. </p>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What difficulty are you encountering with changing the width of the image? I think I'm not understanding what you're trying to do and how I can help.